# How to handle images with unknown dimension for CLS

Tags: html, css, image

To improve the CLS (Cumulative Layout Shift) you are supposed to set the width and height attribute of images. Is there any other proper way to handle images, if it's dimension is unknown?

On my website there is a section were brand logos are displayed. The logo can be different on every page and there is no way to get the size of the image in the backend and set the attributes accordingly.

Is there any other way to handle that properly? The image should not be stretched.

That's the current code:

```css
img {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSgWHIrKgS3d0VR8LASdW4cXFkM5rkWtFDNgw&usqp=CAU" alt="someLogo">
</a>
```

**EDIT:**

I now came up with this solution (don't know if it's best practice, but at least google PageSpeed Insights is not complaining anymore):

```css
a {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSgWHIrKgS3d0VR8LASdW4cXFkM5rkWtFDNgw&usqp=CAU" alt="someLogo">
</a>
```

Comment: Quick question.


In your case, do you know the max size (and for this reason, are setting the max)?


Why I ask, because I have the same problem, but don't have the max sizes 

Comment: @Dihgg In my case it was fine to have a placeholder with a fixed size. The image then would take the placeholders size as max. So the image might not fill the placeholder completely but at least there is no shift. That was the best solution I could come up with. Not sure if this helps you.

Comment: I ended by making a image probe to find it's size in the server side rendering (I'm using React).
[This CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-content-reflow-from-lazy-loaded-images/) article, could help you.